# ISSUE WITH SOAP RETURNING DATA AS STDCLASS OBJECT

Tags: php, soap-client

Data returned over SOAP is returned as objects within an array as shown below.

```
Array (
    [LastPage] => true
    [ListOfContact] => stdClass Object (
        [Contact] => stdClass Object (
            [ContactId] => contactID
            [Description] =>
            [ContactEmail] => emailAddress
        )
    )
)
```

How do i ensure that data is returned as an array only without objects? I am using the SoapClient with the NO WSDL option.

Comment: You should be able to handle it just the same. I am guessing "Contact" will be an array of possibly multiples, so use a foreach on the ListOfContact['Contact'] and it should turn it into a usable array for you.

Comment: yes, "Contact" is an array containing 1 or more items. when i use a foreach as you suggested, i get the error message 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array' So far, the only way i have been able to access the data is using a nested foreach. one to access the ListOfContact object and another to access the Contact object. is there a way for SOAP to return arrays only without objects?

Comment: I added an example as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectArray = YOUR_OBJECT;
foreach ($objectArray['ListOfContact'] AS $contactArray)
{
    $email = $contactArray['ContactEmail'];
    etc...
}
```

Simple example, but should get you on your way!

Comment: my aim is to find a way to avoid using the foreach. is there a way for SOAP to return arrays only without objects? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even if it returns an array, you have to cycle through it with a for,while or foreach, so i am not sure what the difference is here?

Comment: if data was returned as an array with just one item for instance, i would be able to access the item by simply using something along the lines of 

$data = soapResponse;
$contactData = $data['ListOfContact']['Contact'];
$contactEmail = $contactData['contactEmail'];

But with objects, I am not able to do this at all. This is why I am looking for a way to return data without objects.